# Execution in Xcode lagged only in iPhone X

Tags: iphone, xcode, lag

Is there any reason why my application is lagged only when I execute in on an iPhone X and newer models.

In an iPhone 8 plus the app looks like this: [Execution in iPhone 8 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I4cJ.gif)

Whereas in iPhone X it looks like this:
[Execution in iPhone X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZjjI.gif)

Is there any way I can fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to run an sprite-kit game on simulator? If so that is the reason. I bet this will work lot smoother on real device.